# What happens in the background when we declare a pointer to an object of a class having member variable as reference

Tags: c++

I was going through reference variable concepts and found that member variables of a class declared as reference must be initialised in the constructor using initialiser list. but in the folling code i am declaring a pointer to the class and assigning value later to the reference varibales. Can anyone explain me whats happening in the background. why its not giving error as I am not intitialising the member reference variables.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int &a;
        int &b;
        A(int &a, int &b):a(a),b(b){}
};

int main(){
    A *p;
    p->a = 100;
    p->b = 200;
    cout<<"a:"<<p->a<< "b:"<<p->b<<endl;
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Undefined behaviour. You are de-referencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: You never construct an `A` object.

Comment: Just because you seemingly _can_ do something, doesn't mean you **should**. `why its not giving error` I don't know what compiler you're using, but turn on warnings, as you always should, e.g. g++: `main.cpp:14:8: warning: 'p' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: "why its not giving error". A C++ implementation is not required to diagnose all errors. Your error may have better chances of getting found if you increase the warning level, but many error will still go undiagnosed. It's your responsibility to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a reference only once. This is not different whether it is a member of a class or not:

```
int a;
int& b = a;  // <- initialize the reference
int& c;      // NOT OK, references have to be initialized to reference something
```

Any later assignment does not change the variable the reference is referencing, but it changes the value of that variable:

```
int c = 3;
b = c;      // now a==3 but b is still a reference to a
```

Please note that your code has some serious problems that are not actually related to your question. It is already mentioned in comments, but for the sake of completeness: You never create an object and you dereference an invalid pointer leading to undefinded behaviour.

**PS**: I was reading the question again and realized that the problems in your code actually are related to the question.

> What happens in the background when we declare a pointer to an object of a class having member variable as reference?

The answer to this is rather simple and short: Nothing happens in the background. When you declare a pointer you really just declared a pointer. Having a pointer declared relates to creating an object as having a piece of paper where you could write the adress of a house to building a house. But if you merely declare a pointer you neither know the adress nor did you build the house.

Anyhow when I look at your code I can only suggest you to stay away from dynamic allocation and instead simply do this:

```
int main(){
    int a,b;
    A p = A(a,b);
    p.a = 100;
    p.b = 200;
    cout<<"a:"<<a<< "b:"<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```